# Have an error only in production!

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm created project. Works in development mode! Excellent!

DEVELOPMENT:
Typing : `ruby lib/scripts/test_sync.rb`

And my script works!

PRODUCTION: 
Typing : `ruby lib/scripts/test_sync.rb`

Get `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Dont know, I did everything. grant previligies, changed password and so on... Coul someone help me, please?

UPD*

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development:
  adapter:  mysql  
  host:     localhost    
  database: survey_development 
  username: root
  password:  
  encoding: utf8        

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter:  mysql  
  host:     localhost    
  database: survey_development 
  username: root
  password: 
  encoding: utf8

production:
  adapter:  mysql  
  host:     survey
  database: survey_production
  username: survey
  password:
  encoding: utf8

mossad:
  adapter:  mysql  
  host:     baza
  database: baza_production
  username: baza_survey
  password: 
  encoding: utf8
```

Comment: maybe the problem is with your database.yml file, try to run mysql on production with same credentials as you mentioned in your file

Comment: I think the same, but cant see anything critical:S

Comment: maybe the problem is with mossad. Mossad and password don't mix good together.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: where I shoudl write in test-sync.rb yes?

Answer (score 0):

Your login/password pair is incorrect for MySql database in database.yml.

**EDIT**

You should remove your password row if it does not exist:

```
production:
  adapter:  mysql  
  host:     survey
  database: survey_production
  username: survey
  encoding: utf8
```

Comment: i checked about 100 times, everythings ok;[

Comment: Not okey, because `Axxess dinied`. you can show your database.yml

Comment: I have password there.NB!: if i write: if rails_env ="development" it works in production but not in development mode:S  + I dont know why he wants enter in localhost while I'm doing it in production mode :S